# To share data through wifi-hotspot between two mobiles?

Tags: android

I m trying to share data through wifi-hotspot i have search every where but could`t  find any thing..So some body have any idea so please share it..
and it should be through wifi-hotspot not wifi-direct..

//sever code

```
            try {
                ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(400);
                tt.setText("Running");
                while (true)
                {
                    Socket s = ss.accept();
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("sdcard/DCIM/123.jpeg");
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[fis.available()];
                    fis.read(buffer);

                    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                    oos.writeObject(buffer);
                    oos.close();
                    s.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

///client code....

```
            try {
                Socket s = new Socket(txtip.getText().toString(),Integer.parseInt(txtport.toString()));
                ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

                    byte[] buffer = (byte[]) oos.readObject();
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/storage/123.jpeg");
                    fos.write(buffer);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `between to mobiles` ???

Comment: Sorry about that its "Two"...

Comment: Well then edit your post i would say.

Comment: Convert this to a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote some small awful library that did this. You can use Java Sockets.

Have one device run `ServerSocket` in your app, this socket can listen for connections (like server). You need to check on which port this `ServerSocket` is listening (google about it). You will also need to get IP address of this device, there are few way: you can get it from WifiManager (google it).

Other device will use `Socket` class to connect to it. You can send data in multiple forms: plain strings or if you use same app you can serialize/deserialize objects.

Read a bit about sockets, but after `ServerSocket` get connection from other device, you can exchange messages (just keep listening in some loop on other thread).

Comment: `You need to check on which port this ServerSocket is listening`. No. You will your self decide on which port your server is going to listen. And hence wich port the client is going to use.

Comment: `wrote some small awful library that did this`. Nice. But what does it help OP?

Comment: I have tried Seversocket and socket but it is sending text to each other but it didn`t sent images and videos which i want to share..

Comment: Nonsense. You can send and receive all those things using sockets. So write the right code.

Comment: can U share the code please

Comment: @greenapps There is chance that the port will be taken. For high number ports it's pretty much 0 chance that it will be taken, but you never know.

Comment: @zaeemahmed Try sending just text for start. If that works you can move to images, you should probably send it as byte array and rebuild it on other side.

Comment: @greenapps you can look to my code but it isn`t working dont know why..

Comment: @Gudin you can to  look at my code..

Comment: i found my mistake..look like my thread wasn`t working properly..thanks for the help @Gudin